# RSpec: `initialize': FATAL: password authentication failed for user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rspec

My Rails application works perfectly, but when I`m trying to apply some model tests RSpec throws an error:

```
/home/luka/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:655:in `initialize': FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "luka" (PG::ConnectionBad)
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "luka"
```

here is my database.yml file:

```
    default: &default
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    host: localhost
    username: luka
    password: 4129235
    # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
    # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
    pool: 5

    test:
 <<: *default
 database: postdb_test
```

And here is the test I ran:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rails_helper'

describe Student do 
    it "creates valid entry"
end
```

Gemfile:

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record 
gem 'pg'
...
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'devise'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem 'cancancan'
gem 'rspec-rails'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
# Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
   end

 group :development do
 # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in     views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
   end
```

I installed a pg, created user with correct password and created 'postdb' with correct owner. I`ve already changed from peer to md5 in configs. Nothing happened.

UPD: Looks like problem is in "postgres" user. Commands "createdb" and CREATE DATABASE did nothing, so are CREATE USER and ALTER USER

Comment: I think you forgot to create test db, don't you?

Comment: @SergeiStralenia created both 'postdb' and 'postdb_test' just for sure

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct password? Try `psql --username luka --password`

Comment: @max with some woodoo magic I found, that problem was in postgre user (maybe). After sending command I keep getting nothing. psql -l showed none of my databases.

Comment: You would'nt happen to be running Postgres.app on a Mac?

Comment: @max I`m running postgresql app on ubuntu.

Comment: Try commenting out the username/pw. The default is blank on the mac version.

Comment: @max I need it to be ran by exact user

Answer (score 0):

Dunno what it was, but cured with reinstalling postgre.